# Distribution of $L=(1-X)A + X(B + Z C)$, where $X$ and $Z$ are Bernoulli

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let,

$$X\sim\text{Bernoulli}(p),$$

$$A|X=0\sim exp(\text{rate}=\frac{1}{\alpha}),$$

$$B|X=1\sim exp(\text{rate}=\frac{1}{\beta}),$$

$$Z|X=1\sim \text{Bernoulli}(\theta),$$

$$C|Z=1\sim exp(\text{rate}=\frac{1}{\gamma}),$$

> what is the distribution of
>
> $$L=(1-X)A + X\{B + Z C\}$$?

I think $(1-X)$ is another bernoulli with probability $(1-p)$. Also, I know sum of two independent exponential random variables follows gamma distribution. But $B$ and $C$ are conditional. I don't know what is the distribution of product of conditional bernoulli and exponential random variables.

Comment: Hint: Compute the distribution of L conditionally on X=0 and the distribution of L conditionally on X=1.

Comment: @Did for $X=0$, $L\sim exp(rate=\frac{1}{\alpha})$. Is $ZC\sim exp(rate=\frac{1}{\gamma})$?

Comment: If $U_i=exp(\lambda)$, then $\sum_{i=1}^{k}U_i\sim gamma(k,\lambda^{-1})$. But for my given problem, the parameters of $B$ and $C$ are different. It seems difficult to me to compute the distribution of $L$ conditionally on $X=1$.

Comment: The distribution of $L$ conditionally on $X=1$ is a barycenter of the distributions of $V$ and $V+W$ where $V$ and $W$ are independent and exponential with parameters $1/\beta$ and $1/\gamma$. Can you compute the distribution of $V+W$?

Comment: By the way, the statement of your exercise is rather illogical. In fact, one is given independent $(X,Z,A,B,C)$ with respective distributions Bernoulli with parameters $p$ and $\theta$, and exponential with parameters $1/\alpha$, $1/\beta$ and $1/\gamma$ respectively, and one asks for the distribution of $$L=(1-X)A+X(B+ZC)$$

Comment: @Did $(V+W)\sim gamma(2, \beta+\gamma)$. Is it?

Comment: Yes, and now to the distribution of $L$ itself... Can you write its PDF?

Comment: @Did  $L$ is the sum of $exp(\frac{1}{\alpha})=gamma(1, \alpha)$ and $gamma(2,\beta+\gamma)$ random variables. Is $L\sim gamma(3, ?)$? Do not understand what will be the scale parameter.

Comment: You are confusing random variables and their distributions. In terms of PDFs (since $A$, $B$, $B+C$ and $L$ each have a PDF), the result you are after reads $$f_L=(1-p)f_A+p(1-\theta)f_B+p\theta f_{B+C}$$

Comment: @Did That is, $f_L=(1-p)\frac{1}{\alpha}e^{-\frac{a}{\alpha}}+p(1-\theta)\frac{1}{\beta}e^{-\frac{b}{\beta}}+p\theta\frac{1}{\beta+\gamma}e^{-\frac{b+c}{\beta+\gamma}}$?

Comment: ?? Certainly not. Do you get the concept of identity of two *functions*?

Comment: @Did No. From Wikipedia, identity function always returns the same value that was used as its argument. In equations, the function is given by $f(x) = x$.

Comment: Wow. In any case, the displayed identity in my previous comment means that, for every $x$, $$f_L(x)=(1-p)f_A(x)+p(1-\theta)f_B(x)+p\theta f_{B+C}(x)$$

Comment: @Did finally, is this $f_L(x)=(1-p)\frac{1}{\alpha}e^{-\frac{x}{\alpha}}+p(1-\theta)\frac{1}{\beta}e^{-\frac{x}{\beta}}+p\theta\frac{1}{\Gamma 2}(\beta+\gamma)^2x^{2-1}e^{-x(\beta+\gamma)}$? Is the parametrization of  gamma is in rate parameter?

Comment: @Did Another question: $L=(1-X)A+X(B+ZC)=(1-X)A+XB+XZC$. Distribution of $(1-X)A$ is $(1-p)f_A(s)=(1-p)\frac{1}{\alpha}e^{-\frac{s}{\alpha}}$. Why is not distribution of $XB$ is $pf_B(s)=p\frac{1}{\beta}e^{-\frac{s}{\beta}}$ and distribution of $XZC$ is $p\theta f_C(s)=p\theta\frac{1}{\gamma}e^{-\frac{s}{\gamma}}$?

Comment: No the PDF of (1-X)A is not (1-p) times the PDF of A.